# react-navigation doesnt work with react-native-lightbox

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-lightbox

I am writing a project that navigates using react-navigation and i want to use lightbox however lightbox requires Navigator to function properly. I was hoping to see if i could write react-navigation support into the component and then allow a PR to happen. The possibility in my mind is using Navigator + react navigation so that i dont have to re-make my navigation because you could have both "this.props.navigator" and "this.props.navigation" but i am not sure how some of the navigation and navigator functions work.

I have been looking into lightbox.js at the occurences of Navigator and i am searching through the react-navigation api to see if i can find replacements for the functions used as it only occurs 8 times (2 of which are just checks to see if navigator is present).

lightbox.js - navigator occurences

```
open: function() {
         this._root.measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
         this.props.onOpen();

        this.setState({
          isOpen: (this.props.navigator ? true : false),
          isAnimating: true,
          origin: {
            width,
            height,
            x: px,
            y: py,
          },
        }, () => {
          if(this.props.navigator) {
```

> create a route that will work with navigation (for react-navigation it would be the navigationOptions)

```
var route = {
              component: LightboxOverlay,
              passProps: this.getOverlayProps(),
            };
```

> fetch the current set of routes

```
var routes = this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
```

> push a route onto the stack

```
routes.push(route);
```

> some sort of reset for the stack that Navigator does (still looking into it, any help knowing what this does would be nice.

```
this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack(routes);
```

> Then the rest of the code for opening the lightbox runs

```
} else {
                   this.setState({
                     isOpen: true,
                   });
                 }
                 this.setTimeout(() => {
                   this.state.layoutOpacity.setValue(0);
                 });
               });
             });
           },
```

for closing the stack the same lines are called but with .pop() instead of .push()

Anyone with experience of both react-navigation and react-native-lightbox would be a great help.